# esthetics of reverse-inner margin marginpar?

Tags: marginpar

related to [writing on the inner margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429354/writing-on-the-inner-margin) .

I am typesetting a 750 page book in memoir.  (I have certainly had a lot of help from many people on this forum about various problems I have run into---many thanks!)  now, I am just about done --- but as I am finishing up, I wonder about yet another issue.

first, I know that for esthetics, we like good margins in printed books.  I am not sure whether this is because we like white paper, or because the eye does better not reading overly wide lines.  to the extent that it is the latter, I could shift the textblock left or right.  (ok, I don't want zero margins on either side, either, but I hope I am getting the point across.)

now, my book annotates each text paragraph with a short summary --- a few words, a sentence.  it also contains pointers to where a subject was covered in another chapter.  all good.  the material is "side comments," as one would expect.

for location, these marginpars are placed, as traditional, in the outer margins.  but I am thinking now that the outer margin is more valuable in a thick paperback book in which there is a spine (that makes inner material relatively more difficult to view).  in this case, maybe I should put the marginpars in the inner side and shift the main textblock towards the outer margin, rather than how it is now.

before I even think further about how I would do this technically, are there books that have done this?  is this an entirely stupid idea?

Comment: We also like good margins to hold the book  without having to put your fingers on the text and to have the possibility of write margins notes at  hand, preserve text from deteriorating paper edges, and of course a better readability as you pointed, but not only for the number of characters per line. It is an aesthetic based in practical reasons even when reading in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not a printed book, it's probably best to pick one side for margin notes for the whole book, and then, as you said, shift the text to the other side. In printed books usually, since on one page the margin has less space (for example, the left margin has left space on pages on the right side of printed books) they will increase the marginsep which is the space between the margin notes and the boundary of the text body, but this isn't necessary in a non-printed book. Anyway, the way you can increase the size of one margin and move the text is like this, with the `geometry` package: `\usepackage[left=0.5in,marginparwidth=2in,left=0.5in,right=2.5in,marginparwidth=2in,showframe]{geometry}`.
Another way is `\usepackage[left=0.5in,marginparwidth=2in,textwidth=14cm,showframe]{geometry}`. You can play around with the numbers and use `showframe` (which lays the layout in the document) to find out what lengths and widths work best for you.
[image]

Comment: actually, it will be a book.  (thanks for your first contribution ;-).)